# How to enable Datanucleus Support in SpringSource tool suite project

Tags: jdo, spring-roo, datanucleus

I have a Spring Roo project in which I have to use mongoDB using datanucleus and JDO.Presently when I generated all my classes from the below commands then i Found that all the annotations were taken from JPA.

```
//create top level package
project --topLevelPackage com.testproject2 --projectName TestProject2


//persistence setup
persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database MYSQL --databaseName "users" --hostName "127.0.0.1" --userName "root" --password "password"


//typical security
typicalsecurity setup
```

How should i use datanucleus support in my project?

Comment: i am using spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE for generating this project

Comment: --provider DATANUCLEUS is kinda the obvious part.

Comment: using the provider as "--provider DATANUCLEUS" generatesthe necessary code in the persistence.xml. when the command "perform eclipse" is run in the roo shell it throws an error saying that there is a type mismatch w.r.t "TypedQuery" and the project building aborts.
[link](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1imD1kYSZfa5zLm4HYhHinUmP9vNvAD60Ffg6lncyWCY/edit)

Comment: So report a bug with Roo. It's for Spring to fix their software

Answer (score 0):

Simple search on Spring Roo JIRA gives
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-2889

so Spring people have still not added support for JDO. Suggest you vote on it. Obviously you could use JPA annotated classes with JDO persistence, but then JPA annotations only express a subset of the things available with JDO